# Boolean fileContainsString not working

Tags: javascript, fs

I have a function that returns a boolean of whether or not a file contains a string. I know the checkFileForString function runs and properly assigns the boolean value as true but the code within the if statement at the bottom does not run.

```
        var checkFileForString = function (fileName) {

            var yesStringFound = false;

            fs.readFile(fileName, function (err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if(data.indexOf('yes') >= 0){
                    yesStringFound = true;
                }
                console.log('YES STRING FOUND: ' + yesStringFound);
            });
            return yesStringFound;

        };


            console.log("instanceCount >= 4...");
            if (checkFileForString(quadrantFile0) == true) { //todo: confirm and fix
                console.log("runs...");
                assignToQuadrant(0, maxInstances);
                quadrantOccupied = 0;
                setQuadrantAsUnavailable(quadrantOccupied);
            }
```

Comment: Hint: `return yesStringFound` is within your inner function...

Comment: @nnnnnn I updated (see in question) the function but it did not solve the problem, the function still runs and returns the correct boolean value but the if statement does not run

Comment: OK, a more detailed explanation: isn't `.readFile()` method asynchronous? That means the `checkFileForString()` function will return *before* the callback to `.readFile()` is called, and thus return `false` every time. You could restructure your code to return a promise, or pass a callback to `checkFileForString()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn ahh you're right, I tried the synchronous implementation of .readFile()... .readFileSync() which worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solution I got with help from @nnnnnn:

```
        var checkFileForString = function (fileName) {

            var yesStringFound = false;
            var jsonFile = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
            if(jsonFile.indexOf('yes') >= 0)
                yesStringFound = true;

            return yesStringFound;
        };
```

Comment: `function checkFileForString(fileName){ return fs.readFileSync(fileName).includes('yes') }`